# Basic question about matrix algebra- notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

The representation $X=(I_p,0_{n-p\times p})$is confusing me. I get that $I_p$ is an identity matrix with $p$ rows and columns and the rest of the representation is confusing me. Can someone clarify this -simple notation-especially the dimension of $X$?

Comment: More context would definitely help. What book or paper are you seeing this in? Can you post a scan / screenshot of the surrounding text? Can you add examples of how this notation is being used in the source material?

Comment: The answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239352/trace-minimization-with-constraints has this notation. Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo and should read $(I_p, 0_{p\times(n-p)})$.