# Maximizing the trace in an elegant way

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, trace

Suppose $\Lambda = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$, $\Sigma = {\rm diag}(\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n)$, and we have $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n \geq 0$ and $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n \geq 0$. I want to prove that
$${\rm max}[ {\rm Tr}(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O \Sigma)] = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \sigma_i,$$
where $OO^{\rm T} = I$. One approach is to maximize the function
$$f(o_{ij}) = \sum_{i,j} \lambda_i (o_{ij})^2 \sigma_j$$
under the constraint $\sum_{k} o_{ik}o_{jk} = \delta_{ij}$ by Lagrange multiplier method. I can prove the statement in this way but the whole proof is lengthy and lack of the flavor of linear algebra. Since the statement "must be true" intuitively, I want to know if there is an elegant way to prove it. A possible way may be mathematical induction but I failed to make it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Rewritten from the last part of my answer to [Trace minimization with constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239352/trace-minimization-with-constraints/240688#240688) .)*

Since the objective function is continuous and the set of all real orthogonal matrices is compact, the maximum trace is continuous in the entries of $\Sigma$. Therefore, by passing to limit, we may assume without loss of generality that $\Sigma$ has **distinct** diagonal entries.

The matrix exponential of every skew-symmetric matrix is a real orthogonal matrix of determinant one. If $O$ is a global maximiser in your problem, its objective function value must be greater than or equal to the objective function value evaluated at $Oe^{tK}$ (which is real orthogonal) for any real number $t$ and any skew-symmetric $K$. So, if we define $f(t)=\operatorname{tr}(e^{-tK}O^T\Lambda Oe^{tK}\Sigma)$, we must have $f'(0)=0$. Using the cyclic property $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$, we get
$$
0=f'(0)=\operatorname{tr}\left((\Sigma O^T\Lambda O-O^T\Lambda O\Sigma)\, K\right).
$$
Put $K^T=\Sigma O^T\Lambda O-O^T\Lambda O\Sigma$ (which is indeed skew-symmetric), we get $\operatorname{tr}(K^TK)=0$. Hence $K=0$, meaning that $O^T\Lambda O$ commutes with $\Sigma$. Any matrix that commutes with a diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal entries must have all off-diagonal entries equal to zero. Therefore $O^T\Lambda O$ is a diagonal matrix.

Hence $\Lambda_1:=O^T\Lambda O$ is a diagonal permutation of $\Lambda$, because $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda$ are diagonal matrices with the same eigenvalues. Now the problem boils down to finding the diagonal permutation $\Lambda_1$ of $\Lambda$ that maximises $\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda_1\Sigma)$. Obviously, maximum occurs when $\Lambda_1=\Lambda$ or when $O=I$.

Comment: I fixed a small typo

Comment: Great answer by the way.

Comment: This approach is much neater than the naïve Lagrangian multiplier method. In that method we would also arrive at the point that the stable point of the function corresponds to $\Sigma O^T \Gamma O=O^T \Gamma O \Sigma$. Before accepting your answer I want to wait to see if there is an approach without using calculus.

Comment: @EricYang See the linked answer for a far more elegant approach using Birkhoff's theorem. I prefer the current (calculus-based) one, though, because it is applicable in more circumstances.

Comment: @user1551 How beautiful Birkhoff's theorem is. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer.

My contribution is here to show that the issue is equivalent to a **minimization** of a certain difference (in the sense of Frobenius norm) still over all orthogonal matrices in a seemingly more general context. I would have like that this equivalent permits to establish the result, but I haven't succeeded.

$$\begin{eqnarray}\tag{*}M&=&\min_{O \in O(n)}\|O^{\rm T}\Lambda O - \Sigma \|_F^2\\&=&\min_{O \in O(n)}{\rm Tr}[(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O - \Sigma)^T(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O - \Sigma)]\\&=&\min_{O \in O(n)}{\rm Tr}[\Lambda^2+\Sigma^2-(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O \Sigma)-(\Sigma O^{\rm T}\Lambda O)]\\&=&\min_{O \in O(n)}\left\{{\rm Tr}[\Lambda^2+\Sigma^2]-{\rm Tr}[(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O \Sigma)]-{\rm Tr}[(\Sigma O^{\rm T}\Lambda O)]\right\}\\\tag{1}&=&\min_{O \in O(n)}\left\{{\rm Tr}[\Lambda^2+\Sigma^2]-2 \ {\rm Tr}[(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O \Sigma)]\right\}\end{eqnarray}$$

Explanation: ${\rm Tr}[(\Sigma O^{\rm T}\Lambda O)]= {\rm Tr}[(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O \Sigma)]$ because of the following "circulant property" of trace operator:

$$ {\rm Tr}[ABCD]= {\rm Tr}[BCDA]$$

Thus, because of the minus sign in (1), and the fact that ${\rm Tr}[\Lambda^2+\Sigma^2]$ is a fixed quantity, the **minimum** in (1) is indeed attained for an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that

$${\rm Tr}(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O \Sigma) \ \ \text{is maximal}$$

Thus the equivalence betwen (*) and our initial problem is established.

Comment: Dear Jean Marie, this is a neat approach and I like it. Unfortunately I am failing to see how to arrive at the desired result $$\max \mathrm{tr}(O^T\Lambda O \Sigma) = \sum \lambda_i\sigma_i.$$ It seems to me that it remains to prove that $M=\sum_i(\lambda_i-\sigma_i)^2, $ that is, the minimizing matrix $O$ is the identity. Isn't this as hard as the original problem?

Comment: Sorry but I also find it not easy to minimize the Frobenius norm. Please show me a little more hints.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro and Eric Yang : I fully agree. My wrong! The indication in the two last lines is a deadend. I am going to rewrite the last part for taking into account the equivalence with formulation (*).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer given by user1551 is the most appropriate one. The approach using calculus is in detailed in his answer. But another approach using Birkhoff theorem suggested in his comments is rough. I read through the linked answer given by him and try to give an informal summary here to help those interested.

### [Double stochastic matrix and Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix)

Double stochastic matrix is a square matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ of nonnegative real numbers, each of whose rows and columns sums to 1, i.e.
$$\sum _{i}a_{ij}=\sum _{j}a_{ij}=1.$$
The Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem states that if $A$ is doubly stochastic matrix, then there exist $\theta _{1},\ldots ,\theta _{k}\in (0,1)$ and $\theta _{1} + \ldots + \theta _{k} = 1$ and [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $P_{1},\ldots ,P_{k}$ such that
$$A=\theta _{1}P_{1}+\cdots +\theta _{k}P_{k}.$$

The proof of the Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem can be found [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~itamar/courses/Archieves/Packet%20Switching%20Material/bvn.pdf). It applys the Hall's marriage theorem in graph thoery. The proof of the Hall's marriage theorem can be found [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-16.pdf). I have never learned any graph theory before, but I find that the proof given by the link is not hard to follow if you have learned linear algebra. And the proof is also very inspiring and ingenious!

### [Proof of the statement by Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239352/trace-minimization-with-constraints/240688#240688)

If $OO^{\rm T} = I$, we define $Q \equiv (q_{ij}) = (o_{ij})^2$. It is easy to find that $Q$ is double stochastic matrix. Since
$${\rm Tr}(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O\Sigma) = \sum_{i,j}\lambda_i \sigma_j (o_{ij})^2 = \sum_{i,j}\lambda_i \sigma_j q_{ij},$$
we have
$$\max_{OO^{\rm T} = I}{\rm Tr}(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O\Sigma) \leq \max_{A} \sum_{i,j}^n\lambda_i \sigma_j a_{ij}, A \mbox{ is double stochastic}
.$$

In light of Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem, we have
$$A=\sum_{l=1}^{k}\theta_l P_{l},$$
where $\theta _{1},\ldots ,\theta _{k}\in (0,1)$ and $\theta _{1} + \ldots + \theta _{k} = 1$. So we have
$$\sum_{i,j}\lambda_i \sigma_j a_{ij} = \sum_{l=1}^{k} \theta_{l} \sum_{i,j}\lambda_i \sigma_j p_{ij} .$$
Among all $n!$ permutation matrices, it is easy to check $\sum_{i,j}\lambda_i \sigma_j p_{ij}$ has maximum value $\sum_{i}\lambda_i \sigma_i$ when $p_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$. So we have
$$\max_{A} \sum_{i,j}\lambda_i \sigma_j a_{ij} = \sum_{i}\lambda_i \sigma_i.$$
On the other hand, we have ${\rm Tr}(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O\Sigma) = \sum_{i}\lambda_i \sigma_i$ when $O = I$, so we can conclude that
$$\max_{OO^{\rm T} = I}{\rm Tr}(O^{\rm T}\Lambda O\Sigma) = \sum_{i}\lambda_i \sigma_i.$$

Thanks a lot to [user 1551](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1551/user1551) for showing me these exciting new knowledge!

Comment: Thank you for this post! I was interested in that proof, and I followed the given link but got a bit discouraged.

Comment: The Birkoff-von Neumann looks like a special case of [the Krein-Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem).
P.S.: Confirmed, [see Simon "Convexity an analytical viewpoint"](https://books.google.es/books?id=xWCs0lWGxjkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA235#v=onepage&q&f=false), pag. 235.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!