# Trace of commuting matrices is maximal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $A,B$ be two symmetric positive-definite matrices, and let

$$A=U\Lambda U^T,\qquad B=V\Gamma V^T$$

be their eigenvalue decompositions, where $U,V$ are orthogonal matrices and $\Lambda,\Gamma$ are diagonal, containing the (positive) eigenvalues of $A,B$.

By generating random matrices $A,B$ with these properties, I have numerical evidence that the following inequality seems to hold in general:

$$\mathrm{Tr}(AB) \le \mathrm{Tr}(\Lambda\Gamma)$$

Is it true? If so how can I prove it? (If not, please provide a counter-example).

Comment: It's is true and is a special case of *von Neumann's trace inequality*. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075288) for a proof, for instance.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Von_Neumann's_trace_inequality_and_related_results

Comment: @becko Thanks, but I think I'll close this question as an abstract duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed the link to the other question. Yes ok, I'll close myself.

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558297/maximizing-the-trace-in-an-elegant-way  which is a more direct and easier result (also: it plus cauchy-schwarz implies von - Neumann trace inequality)