# Variational formulation of PCA?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier

I have the intuition that PCA (Principal Component Analysis) can be formulated as the following constrained optimization problem.

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ symmetric and positive semi-definite real matrix. Let

$$L = \sum_{i=1}^m \vec v_i^TA\vec v_i$$

where $\vec v_i$ are $m$ real $n$-dimensional vectors. Now maximize $L$ with respect to the vectors $\{v_i\}$, subject to the constrain that these vectors be of unit norm and orthogonal to each other. Assume that $m \le n$.

For the sake of educating my intuition, I need to prove or disprove the following statement:

The maximization of $L$ defined above (with the constrains given) results in the $\vec v_i$ being the eigenvectors of $A$ associated to its $m$ largest eigenvalues.

I tried to do this by Lagrange multipliers, but it gets very messy and I think I am overlooking some simple way of thinking about this.

Comment: Uwe Helmke, John B. Moore, [Optimization and Dynamical Systems](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B04.PDF), 2nd edition, March 1996.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Is there a section/chapter of that book addressing this?

Comment: There's a section on computing singular values using ODEs. Is it a gradient descent flow? What is the cost being minimized? Does this relate in any way to your question?

Comment: Might be easier to work with matrices. If you put the $v_i$'s in the columns of matrix $V$ then you're working on a Stiefel manifold.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Ok, so I can also write $L = \mathrm{Tr}(V^TAV)$. But I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: I would say it helps because you can use a Lagrange multiplier matrix. The fewer symbols, the better. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3308987/339790).

Comment: Take a look at page 9 of Bandeira's [lecture notes](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~abandeira/TenLecturesFortyTwoProblems.pdf).