# Maximizing weighted sum of eigenvalues of a matrix ($\Lambda_1 U^\top \Lambda_2 U \Lambda_1$)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Let $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2$ be $n\times n$ diagonal matrices with diagonal elements positive and decreasing (i.e., $\Lambda_{j,11}>\Lambda_{j,22}\ldots>\Lambda_{j,nn}>0$ for $j\in\{1,2\}$). Let $\{a_i\}$ be another decreasing sequence of positive numbers. I want to find the orthonormal matrix $U$ that maximizes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d a_i\cdot \mathrm{eigval}_i(\Lambda_1 U^\top \Lambda_2 U \Lambda_1),
$$
where $\mathrm{eigval}_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i$-th largest eigenvalue of a matrix.

I think the optima should satisfy $U^2 = I$. This would be true if we restricted $U$ to be a permutation matrix, or if $a_i\equiv 1$ held, or if we were doing a greedy optimization of the sum (first choosing the first column $U_{:,1}$ while leaving the other columns to be zero, then choosing $U_{:,2}$ in the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{span}\{U_{:,1}\}$, etc). But the general form of the problem makes e.g. using the first-order condition difficult.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I find a proof. Define $a_{d+1}:=0$. Then our objective function equals
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^d (a_i-a_{i+1})\sum_{j=1}^i \mathrm{eigval}_j (U^\top \Lambda_2 U \Lambda_1^2)
&\le 
\sum_{i=1}^d (a_i-a_{i+1})\sum_{j=1}^i \mathrm{eigval}_j (U^\top \Lambda_2 U)\; \mathrm{eigval}_j(\Lambda_1^2) \\ 
&= 
\sum_{i=1}^d a_i \;\mathrm{eigval}_i(U^\top \Lambda_2 U)\;\mathrm{eigval}_i(\Lambda_1^2),
\end{aligned}
$$
where we use the property $\mathrm{eigval}_i(AB)=\mathrm{eigval}_i(BA)$ for s.p.d. $A,B$, and the inequality is from [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106191/eigenvalues-of-the-product-of-two-symmetric-matrices). (As the diagonal matrices have positive and decreasing diagonal elements,) equality is attained when $U^2=I$.

It remains to prove these are the only solutions. Another application of the aforementioned inequality yields
$$
\text{Objective} \le \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} (a_i-a_d) \;\mathrm{eigval}_i(U^\top \Lambda_2 U)\;\mathrm{eigval}_i(\Lambda_1^2) + 
a_d \mathrm{Tr}(U^\top \Lambda_2 U \Lambda_1^2). 
$$
For the trace term to be maximized it [must hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308987/trace-minimization-in-a-rayleigh-quotient-like-problem) that $U^2=I$, and these choices of $U$ attain the equality here. Therefore, they are the only optimas.